# Implement conditions in logic-less mustache template engine

Tags: jquery, templates, conditional-statements, mustache

So far [`mustache`](http://mustache.github.com/) is great, but logic-less now does not seem to be a feature. Suppose, I have to render template in which I can have user's email and name.

If both email and name are present I want my rendered result to be:

```
<a href="mailto:EMAIL">NAME</a>
```

If email is present, but not name, the result would be:

```
<a href="mailto:EMAIL">EMAIL</a>
```

If just name is present, template should be rendered to:

```
NAME
```

So now I have to do something like:

```
{{#email}}<a href="mailto:{{email}}">{{#name}}{{name}}{{/name}}{{^name}}{{email}}{{/name}}</a>{{/email}}{{^email}}{{name}}{{/email}}
```

This is SO UGLY! And this is just 3 conditions! What if I will need more? I feel like there should be another way of doing the same in `mustache`. Or shouldn't it?

So, mustache developers think that being logic-less is a good thing, but I have an argument. Most of the times we need to check some variable in template (most of the times we just need to check only existence). So I would do something like:

```
{% if email %}{{ email }}{% else %}{{ name }}{% endif %}
```

and this looks much more comprehensive then

```
{{#email}}{{email}}{{/email}}{{^email}}{{name}}{{/email}}
```

isn't it?

If I need to check `name` too:

```
{% if email %}{{email}}{% elif name %}{{name}}{% else %}Anonymous{% endif %}
```

vs

```
{{#email}}{{email}}{{/email}}{{^email}}{{#name}}{{name}}{{/name}}{{^name}}Anonymous{{/name}}{{/email}}
```

If no, would you suggest another templating library for rendering templates in `javascript`? Integration with `jQuery` (jQuery-plugin) is an advantage, but not a requirement - I can do it on my own.

Thanks.

Comment: check this out: http://garann.github.com/template-chooser/

Comment: Some Mustache implementations accept the `{{#foo}}...{{^foo}}...{{/foo}}` syntax, which is a little shorter. Some even accept `{{#foo}}...{{^}}...{{/}}`. Yet, Mustache is still verbose, for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's always [Handlebars](http://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/) which is a little more feature rich than vanilla Mustache (it's a superset of Mustache), and of course you can use any of the other countless templating engines available for JS. If you go with Handlebars you could even reimplement a version of the `{{#if}}` block helper that accepts multiple arguments, like this (warning: very slightly tested, writing mostly out of the top of my head)

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if', function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        options = args.splice(-1, 1)[0],
        allPass = true,
        context;

    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        context = args[i];

        if(Object.prototype.toString.call(context) === "[object Function]") { 
            context = context.call(this);
        }

        if (!context || Handlebars.Utils.isEmpty(context)) {
            allPass = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(allPass) {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

and use it like this:

```
var template = "{{#if a b c}}pass{{else}}fail{{/if}}";
var c = Handlebars.compile(template);
console.log(c({a: true, b: pass, c: true}))
```

Be aware that this can be considered "cheating" by purists as you are implementing some kind of a compound logic operator, even more making it accept an indeterminate amount of params. 
The point of Mustache is to have a very minimal [spec](https://github.com/mustache/spec/) that is easily ported across programming languages so that you can interchangeably reuse your templates in the back end and front end.